# Two Objects Made from the Same Class Using Different Import Methods, isinstance() == False

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest

I am trying to unittest some dynamic imports within a project at work. My thought was to manually import the class I expect to be loaded dynamically and verify that the dynamically created object was in fact an instance of the class I manually imported.

So far I have not been able to get this to work. Here is some example code that hopefully explain what I mean.

**SomeApi:**
This is the class that will be loaded dynamically later.

The path to this file is /path/to/file/SomeApi.py

```
class SomeApi(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "a"
        self.b = "b"
        self.c = "c"
```

**Unittest File**
This is the file where I will perform my tests. It will import SomeApi manually as well as dynamically.

```
from path.to.file.SomeApi import SomeApi


class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def import_test():
        dyn_loaded_module = importlib.import_module("Path.to.file.SomeApi", "SomeApi")
        dyn_loaded_class = getattr(dyn_loaded_module, "SomeApi")
        dyn_loaded_api = dyn_loaded_class()  # Create an instance of the dynamically imported class.
        manual_import_api = SomeApi()  # Create an instance of the manually loaded class.
        assert isinstance(manual_import_api, SomeApi)  # This returns True as expected.
        assert isinstance(dyn_loaded_api, SomeApi)  # This returns False, I am not sure why.
```

So basically my question is, why is the dynamically created object not an instance of the manually imported class.

Also, is this the correct way to go about testing this?

Comment: Have you compared `id(SomeApi)` and `id(dyn_loaded_class)`. Sounds like they are two separate class objects defined using the same code.

Comment: I had not. I just tried it and the IDs returns are not the same.

Comment: There you go. They are two separate classes with the same name; an instance of one is not an instance of the other.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Is there another way I can verify the class I import dynamically is in fact the class I meant to import?

Comment: Not sure; I can't actually reproduce the error; both objects are, in fact, instances of `SomeApi` when I run it.

Comment: Scratch that last comment. It looks like when I do the importlib.import_module call it is overwriting my manual import. I made an instance of BaseApi before doing the dynamic import and the IDs are no longer the same.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me with both imported classes using the same ID.